# Exporting tiff for use in photoshop problems

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, geotiff-tiff

I am working with a section of the SRTM DEM in .tiff format (8bit unsigned integer) in ArcGIS 10.3. I want to export the data in order to do some modifications in photoshop. However when I export data (tried different formats and compressions) and try to open it in photoshop I keep getting completely black or a partially black images in photoshop.

Does someone know where I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  We can't tell you if you're doing something wrong as you haven't describe the process or processes you have followed in your various attempts at exporting the data.  Please [edit] your question to tell us what you've actually tried, in detail.